# how can I see the changes that were applied locally after an svn update?

Tags: svn

After an svn update I want to see the changes made to the updated files.
I usually do so by doing something like:

```
svn log -l 2 modifiedFile     # copy penultimate revision number 
svn diff -r penultimateRevNum modifiedFile
```

But this is quite tedious, specially when several files are involved.
Recently I've learned a more convenient way to do this:

```
svn diff -r BASE:PREV modifiedFile
```

But this method has a problem. If there were more than one modification committed to this file I only get the difference with the previous modification.

What I would really want is a simple way to see on the console all the modifications applied on the last update.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without filename?

```
svn diff -rPREV
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: I'm afraid this only shows differences with previous revision, not all the revisions that were merged during the last `svn update` command

Comment: So is it okay for you?

Comment: As I said in my question, "what I would really want is a simple way to see on the console **all** the modifications applied on the **last** update". Your solution only shows differences with previous commit, but the `svn update` can involve merging with more than only commit at once.

Answer (score 0):

To see the changes that were made to your local working copy when doing `svn up`, not including the changes *you* may have made to files in your local working copy:

```
svn diff -rPREV:HEAD
```

This does a diff between the previous commit and the state of your working copy since the last time you made a commit.